# .Paste Method where `,` is the decimal mark

Tags: excel, vba

I'm grabbing data from SAP to paste into my Excel sheet via VBA. (There are other methods for exporting data, but this is the one I am limited to.)

The data is put into the Windows-Clipboard via SAP. Afterwards it is put into the newest Excel-Worksheet (see `Sub importStuff` and then formatted see `Sub divData`) The data is delimited with pipes `|` and after pasting it looks like this (including the blanks):

`|  FOO: BAR              |       360.000 |`

After I Call `divData` it is split into two separate columns. (this how I want it to be formatted)

`[SOME_ID: SOME_NAME][360.000]`

Sometimes Excel formats `360.000` to `360,000` = `360`. This only happens for values that end in a `0`. So `360.000` is formatted to `360`, `312.312.001.800` would be formatted to `312.312.001,80`.

I'm using a German version of Excel 14.0.7166.5000 (32-Bit). So a `.` is for digit grouping, a `,` is the decimal mark.

This my code

```
Sub importStuff()

dBegin = wsUeb.Range("BeginPlan")
dEnd = wsUeb.Range("EndPlan")

'lots 
'of 
'other 
'SAP-Stuff

SAP_Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTAB/tabpPUSH4/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTAB:ZCO_SUSAETZE_NEW:0400/ctxtP_LAYOUT").Text = "/ZL_UMSPIEXP"
    SAP_Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
    SAP_Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[45]").press
    SAP_Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[4,0]").Select
    SAP_Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Paste
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "Plan-Umsaetze " & dBegin & " - " & dEnd

Call divData

End Sub

Sub divData()

ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone, _
ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
Other:=True, _
OtherChar:="|"

End Sub
```

Here is what happens.

1. I open the workbook
2. I call `importStuff`
3. I call `divData` afterwards, doesn't matter if it is called within `importStuff` or not
4. everything is fine
5. I call `importStuff` again
6. I don't call `divData` at all (doesn't matter if I do)
7. I get erroneous values

But if I just press `Ctrl+v` the values get inserted just fine (see 4.)).

I can't call `Ctrl+v` via Windows Shell, because the new worksheet is invisible for the user.

Comment: You can try to format the cells in your new sheet as text.

Comment: Nice! It worked. I formatted the column to text, imported the data, changed the format back to numbers and then multiplied each value with `1`. That did the trick. Feel free to post this as an answer @Jochen , so I can accept it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just Jochen's and my comment posted as an answer. I had the same issue today, that's why I necro'd this post.

I formatted the column to text, imported the data, changed the format back to numbers and then multiplied each value with 1. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you could set `Range.numberFormat`

or use `Range.PasteSpecial( [xlPasteTypes], [xlPasteOperation])`, doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx), particularly `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` or `xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply`

Comment: Maybe I should've added that to my orignial question, but I already tried that and it didn't work. See comments under question to see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I can solve it by:

```
range("A1").PasteSpecial(-4142)
```

it seems like excel sees "---------" as calculation.