# Why is VBA changing my decimal format?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a spreadsheet with VBA functions in a PT-BR (comma as decimal) Excel. Everything works fine.

But a client (running it on EN-US) had a weird issue: decimal numbers, such as 3.88888 were copied as hole numbers, like 388888. Numbers with less decimal cases, like 2.5, get copied as 2,5, and not recognized as numbers.

My function is just copying the value, like this:

> ResultsSheet.Cells(row, 3).Value=DataSheet.Cells(row, 11).value

Unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce this issue. On either language setting, I get correct results - which is what I would expect.

Anyone having experienced this, or pointing me to some information would be greatly appreciated. I would also help with clues on how to reproduce my client's issue.

Comment: This does sound like a thousands/decimals separator issue.  Where you have a decimal point in a position that could be a thousand separator the value may be interpreted as an integer (e.g. 1.001 <--> 1,001); where the point is not in such a position (e.g. 2,5) that will look like text.  Are the numbers in the source sheet formatted as text?  Then they will get copied as text (exactly as displayed), entered as text in the destination and then Excel will (wrongly) convert them to numbers using a different locale.

Comment: They are formated as numbers. I am pretty sure it's the decimal thing, but I don't know where (probably VBA) it is getting back to PT-BR. Is there a locale setting inside VBA, different from the one on excel?

Comment: Some light will be shed when my client tests the same spreadsheet, but after I saved it in EN-US - after inserting a blank line on the code and saving.

Comment: @RSinohara I think i had a similar issue a while back, maybe this can help. See comments under question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830369/paste-method-does-not-work-correctly-behaves-differently-than-ctrl-v

Comment: @Tom, my question actually seems like a dupe from that one... Which I couldn't find when searching, so let's give this one a try - Also, I don't think the answer works for me, as the cols are number-formated (with zero decimal cases, but vba will pick the whole number.

Comment: btw: I'm not a 100% sure about this, but I think with Office Live you can maybe test this in different locales.

Comment: @Tom I got 2 boxes each with one language, I tried saving in one, opening on another, running the macro in one and opening on the other, etc... can't repro it (although I can't try every combo of excel and windows locale, and number formats...)

Comment: Is this how you did that? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162397.aspx

Comment: @Tom No, I choose a different language on each box when I first installed it... I figured it would come in handy... I never trust the concept of Excel translating formulas.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, quite tricky to recreate the problem, but type conversion with some checks should work, snippet below.

```
If InStr(DataSheet.Cells(Row, 11).Value, ",") > 0 Then
    'check if text contains a comma, and if so replace with "."
    ResultsSheet.Cells(Row, 3).Value = CDec(Replace(DataSheet.Cells(Row, 11).Text, ",", "."))
Else
    If IsNumeric(Cells(r, 11).Value) Then
    'check if numeric and ensure decimal value on ResultsSheet
        ResultsSheet.Cells(Row, 3).Value = CDec(DataSheet.Cells(Row, 11).Text)
    Else
    'if text then just copy
        ResultsSheet.Cells(Row, 3).Value = DataSheet.Cells(Row, 11).Value
    End If
End If
```

Hope this solves your issue. Boa Sorte ^^.

Miguel